# Is it possible for non-javascript HTML to POST to a different domain? ... in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: html, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, post

I'm not using AJAX, JSON, JSONP, or [CORS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/02/20/implementing-cors-support-in-asp-net-web-apis.aspx).

Is it possible to simply use HTML forms to POST to another domain?  Can this be done in ASP.NET MVC4?  I don't see an overload to test this.

Research I've done...

- Read the standards regarding AJAX, JSON, JSONP, and CORS... it appears the POST domain restriction is limited to javascript based POSTs... nothing about HTML based posts.
- I tried to test this myself, in MVC, but I'm unsure how to hack it so I can Post the HTML.  There is no overload as shown below

code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
     {
         @Html.ValidationSummary(true) 

 <div class="editor-label">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ServerTarget)
 </div>
```

**Test #2**

I created a HTML form in my view that looks like this:

The target web server, running on a different port on the same machine looks like this: (note in the future I'd rather have a different name not just a different port)

**Source Web HTML**

```
     <form action="@Model.ServerTarget" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" autocomplete="on">

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ResponseURL)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ResponseURL)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ResponseURL)
        </div>

    </form>
```

**Target Web Controller, on different port**

The string "data" is null below.

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string data)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: It is possible. I have done it using strongly typed models. In your case, I am not sure but renaming your `data` variable to `ResponseURL` should solve your problem.